# YUI 3 : Trigger auto complete suggestion through input programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, yui3

Well I was testing a input text say country box with which yui3 autocomplete plugin is attached.

My task is to trigger this autocomplete suggestion by entering value in input box through javascript.

I have tried countryNode.set('value','usa'); gives no suggestion to me. Obviously I have plug autocomplete in countrynode before using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an `AutoCompleteList` instance you can call `.sendRequest` with the current value of the input.

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/AutoCompleteList.html#method_sendRequest